# What's the best way to handle Poster deleting their code in an edit to avoid Plagiarism search

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks, rollback-wars

Running across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23420980/2587435) just now, made me curious as how to handle a situation in which a user (mostly students) delete their code to avoid plagiarism hits in a search by their professor.

It makes sense to me why they'd want it deleted, by what this does most of the time, is invalidate some answers to the post. I've in the past rolled back the edit, just to have the poster re-edit it. Some times after a few back and forth, I'll just flag the post to be blocked.

There's an moral dilemma here. At one end, you don't want the user to get docked by the professor. On the the other end, it is not good for SO to have the code removed. So what is the best way to handle this situation?

If the way I'm handling it is correct, what response should a provide to a Poster who keeps trying to re-edit my roll backs, so they understand, as to not *have* to flag to a moderator as the last resort?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're doing about all you can.  Users can't stop the owner of a post from editing it; all they can do is reverse the damage and/or call in someone who can lock the post.

I might recommend that when you roll back, you add a comment informing the user that people can't simply delete their questions once they get an answer.  (If you think they actually care, ask them how useful SO would be if everyone did that, and as a result there were no questions, let alone answers.)

If they don't stop, though...do what you've been doing.  :P

Comment: Can you provide an example of an comment _you_ would leave. Maybe I'll plagiarize _that_ ;)

Comment: @peeskillet: Copy/pasting what i personally would say to such a vampire, might be counter-productive.  :)  My experience with that type has been that most of them don't give a damn about etiquette, TOS, or reciprocity.  They just don't want to get caught getting help with their homework.  I don't even try to explain unless i detect a hint of decency.

Answer (score 4):

It should be up to the community to decide what stays and goes on SO, not a single person - including the OP.  I don't know if it's the *"right"* thing to do, but as a matter of course I roll-back any attempt I see to destroy content regardless of the reason.  Poor quality questions can be improved and sensitive information can be removed - it doesn't seem very community spirited otherwise.

Any issue's surrounding plagiarism are between them and their board of education.  Regarding that post in particular I doubt they have anything to worry about - they got a good answer to the problem with an explanation of what they were doing wrong - learning from that isn't plagiarism.  If they are worried about other people on the same course copying their code, then they should highlight this before they submit their work.

It's not *entirely* clear what they mean by plagiarism in this case but if there's some other reason we don't know about then frankly there's a life-lesson in there somewhere...

Comment: "I doubt they have anything to worry about" -- I believe one common problem isn't that the questioner has actually committed plagiarism, it's that because their code now appears on the internet, plagiarism-checking software thinks they have. Yes, it's between them and their board of education, and probably they should have radically changed their code before asking questions about it in public. But the ship has sailed on that, and for a number of reasons some institutions take a pretty strict, "your homework must not contain code found on the internet for any reason" policy.

Comment: ... so possibly the questioner has committed an academic offence by asking a question on SO not because the help they received amounts to plagiarism, but because to make it easier to convict people of plagiarism the institution has in effect said you must not show your code to anyone, and will be convicted of plagiarism if you do. The life-lesson might be, "those in authority create over-broad criminal legislation because it's the only sure way to catch the serious crooks. If you don't like it go to Russia [or USA if already in Russia]" ;-)

Comment: Plagiarism detection flags potential issues but at the end of the day there's surely still a human element that can verify it, *"Ye that's Stack Overflow, we were made aware of that - we'll let that slide..."?* Do we know of any institutions with such strict criteria? It sounds somewhat restrictive to the learning process - in any case it still shouldn't be the community's responsibility if someone decides to chance it.

Comment: I've heard rules stated on Academia.SE "homework turned in must not appear anywhere else", I don't know whether that's really enforced. Sure, it's not the community's responsibility. If the rules they work under stop them asking a good question on SO, then they shouldn't ask. It's just that you said the particular person in question isn't plagiarising and has nothing to worry about. In cases where what they've done is treated harshly, they do have something to worry about even if we disagree with their institution's catching it under "anti-plagiarism".

Comment: ... in a way though, it's good training for professional software development. Professionals also can't post their *real* code to SO, it doesn't belong to them. So the "correct" solution is to learn to write a minimal test case, and at best that student is trying to recover a situation where they made a mistake to begin with. You can quite reasonably say "not my problem, let them burn" :-)