# Make deleted posts searchable for 30 days

Tags: feature-request, search, deleted-questions

I regularly teach programming classes. Like most instructors, I occasionally see students that I know to be both lazy and weak turn in suspiciously good projects and sometimes am able to locate online code that they had plagiarized. Some schools use automated tools for that, but mine doesn't. I don't obsess about it, but if something jumps out at me I'll sometimes spend the time to investigate it. Stack Overflow is naturally one of the places that I'd search.

But -- I just observed someone post what seems like a clear homework problem in the Python tag (a problem with this tag since so many intro-to-programming courses are now taught using Python -- which brings to mind [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html) wonderful essay). Within minutes someone answered the question, giving a complete solution, and then shortly after that OP deleted the question. It occurred to me that this opens up a sort of loophole for easy plagiarism (I don't know if this was OP's intent -- they could have just been responding to the down-votes that their question received).

This loophole can be at least partially closed by making all deleted questions (and not just the user's deleted questions) searchable for a period of time, say 30 days. Since 10k is the threshold for viewing deleted questions that can also be made for searching deleted questions, though there could also perhaps be a way for instructors with less than 10k rep be able to signup with an instructor status that allows them to do the searching.

Comment: I agree with this suggestion but not just for instructors, since how could you possibly verify who is an instructor and who isn't? but rather for everyone.

Comment: Related with regard to the instructor/homework part: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295420/how-to-cope-with-complaints-from-tutors-who-want-to-fight-cheaters and on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270605/teacher-request-remove-homework-questions

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels   The suggestion was for this ability for everyone who has enough rep plus, maybe, instructors with less rep. Textbook publishers have ways to verify instructors before giving them access to online solution manuals, so there must be some way to verify, though I don't how easy it is to implement.

Comment: John, I agree that it's possible, but it would cost something in time, resources and money, and would this verification be a worthwhile cost for the stackexchange site? I doubt it.

Comment: @rene Thanks for the links. I don't object to students asking questions related to homework, as long as they show work and ask for pointers rather than complete solutions.

Comment: On the delete after answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260692/how-to-handle-users-deleting-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253214/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-poster-deleting-their-code-in-an-edit-to-avoid-pla

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I suspect that you are right -- which is why I prefixed that part of the feature request with "perhaps".

Comment: If you flag a post (pretty much any) for moderator attention, with the link to the question you saw, they'll probably reinstate the question due to the effort put in on the answer, and even upvote the answer to prevent the questioner deleting again.

Comment: @BillWoodger No need to involve mods, just getting the attention of a few 10K's is enough. Like in a chat-room mostly for moderation (SOCVRR comes to mind), or on meta.

Comment: @BillWoodger: For that to work, it is up to some concerned citizen, perhaps the answerer to monitor his answers and check that the question hasn't been deleted. Many folks here don't do this.

Comment: @BillWoodger Homework questions can be hard to distinguish from clueless questions so I wouldn't want a clueless questioner to be unable to delete a bad question. The feature request is intended for essentially forensic purposes so that if a student plagiarizes a Stack Overflow answer then it is harder for them to cover their tracks.

Comment: @JohnColeman This would likely be a privilege - instructors with less rep won't probably be given this privilege of searching deleted posts. However, in the mean time (as I see you have 10k), you can use the [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) available to you, and you should be able to find a pane with posts that have been recently deleted. I don't have 10k here, and I definitely don't know the volume of deleted posts here, but it may be of some use.

Comment: @Zizouz212 that is a very small subset and for the amount of traffic on SO not very useful for the purpose of finding posts.

Comment: @rene Yeah, I figured as much. I guess I'm too used to mod tools on beta sites :P

Comment: "someone answered the question, giving a complete solution" if the solution itself was useful is the case I was thinking of. A clueless question with a one-line answer doesn't matter to anyone if the asker deletes. There'd be no point arranging for that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was thinking that the asker here had noted that case, and may have the link. If useful content, get it back, despite the wishes of the asker.

Comment: @BillWoodger: I agree, and that's why I support this request.

Comment: @Deduplicator OK, noted. Is SOCVRR the one where rene lives?

Comment: I'm afraid it is ...

Comment: @rene super, I already know how to get there :-)

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the request. When you say "searchable," do you mean, "Google can catalog these and they will come up in search results," or are you asking for a specific, "Search deleted recent posts," feature built into StackExchange?

Comment: We all can agree that the behavior of the OP deleting his post immediately after receiving a satisfactory answer is a bad one, one that is selfish and that does not promote the philosophy of this site, to share common problems and high-quality answers with all, and that is sometimes done to obtain answers for homework and yet evade the prying eyes of instructors. And while many believe (such as @SarahManning) that preventing this behavior is beyond the purview of this site, and yet **not** preventing it potentially encourages its repeat, and so... maybe it is within the purview of this site.

Comment: Whilst it may be a nice idea in principle, it would fall over very easily by the OP just replacing the questions content with "-- deleted --" (at least for the question anyway)

Comment: @jpmc26 Since they would remain deleted, the answer is most probably the latter.

Comment: @Sayse there's always the revisions history...

Comment: Strange, I thought that an answered question could not be deleted by the OP. It happened to me once.

Comment: @cullub - Yes but edit revisions do not show up in searches which would make it incredibly hard for the OP to find posts they appear to be looking for

Comment: @Sayse True, very true. Hmm... Maybe make it so an OP's edits get immediately shown live, but they still go to a special review queue where they will mostly be accepted, but if it's a bad edit such as in your example, it could be easily reverted.

Comment: ...Or, [after being declined by, say, 500 rep users (or 6 - I don't know)], it could get sent to a higher review queue (for 1k users, or something), where it would be (mostly) bad edits, and could get easily reverted by them.

Comment: I would very much like an `is_deleted` search filter, if only for my own sanity. I'm pretty sure I see several posters playing the 'delete quick so it doesn't get downvoted' game. Which is fine, to a point (after all, if it's junk, then allowing the user to remove it is ok). But then, there's sometimes questions that I think _shouldn't_ be deleted, that I ... just can't find any more.

Answer (score 107):

Let me suggest another way this could be handled: tighten the self-deletion restrictions so that a question with *any* answer cannot be deleted by the asker.

At present, a question with two or more answers or a single upvoted answer cannot be deleted by the asker. This is to prevent someone from taking their ball and going home after they get their answer. Unfortunately, questions that receive good answers can be quickly deleted by askers before people have the time to vote for an answer or provide others.

What if the presence of any answer blocked a question from being deleted by the asker? That would stop the behavior you describe without the downsides of making deleted posts searchable.

Would it harm the overall post quality of the site? I don't know. Would moderators get more flags from people demanding that their questions be deleted? Sure, but we already get tons of those and they are easy to decline. We've seen every lame excuse from a student you can imagine.

Comment: This would solve the problem but would introduce another in that it would directly increase the amount of crap on the site.

Comment: No! I want to be able to delete my questions that some poor soul cared to answer before I realised my stupidity and before it affects others.

Comment: @TylerH - Would it? I'm not so sure. I've undeleted plenty of great answers to questions deleted like this. The kind of person who is sharp enough to quickly delete their question once it receives a good answer generally doesn't fit the profile of our worst askers. I'm curious about the stats on these questions, and I don't have an easy query to pick them out.

Comment: @BradLarson I should specify that I meant it would increase the amount of *visible* crap on the site.

Comment: I believe it has been suggest before that this could be time limited. (A question with an answer cannot be deleted for *n* hours or *n* days to ensure the answer has a chance to be upvoted.)

Comment: I have even seen an OP edit the question to "please delete this as I am not supposed to ask for homework help".  I like this suggestion as SO is answer-centric and the OP should not be able to delete a useful answer.

Comment: How about any question with at least one answer cannot be removed for 48 hours. During this time the community should be able to up vote valid and good answers.

Comment: @vikingosegundo That seems like the obvious approach to the problem. I totally agree with it. Why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: What if we queued (instead of outright deleted) these questions, and just like close-voting, required five votes before we obliterate them?

Comment: @jpmc26: Yep, I proposed that as an answer to [this MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202633/157398).

Comment: What about typo questions..? [I asked a question that was entirely caused by a typo. There is an answer that pointed out the typo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34534710/2333214) the fact that I typed "remaning" instead of "remaining" is really not going to be useful for any future readers. Unfortunately it didn't get enough close votes since I got the answer quickly and accepted it, so only few people actually even viewed it. Is it bad to delete it myself..? At this point I think I'll be able to delete it. Your suggestion will make it impossible

Comment: Mark for deletion? Answerers get notification, can vote against.

Comment: I agree with TJ.  Also, what if you post a question that gets a poor answer, and no other answers, maybe because the question wasn't very well phrased.  The questioner needs the ability to apply own quality control and delete the question themselves, rather than begging for close votes.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão then **think twice** before asking a question.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão "before it affects others" I find this part funny.

Comment: @gsamaras everyone does mistakes we should allow them to fix them by themselves.

Comment: @BradLarson, unfortunately this is no feature yet? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367329/i-answered-a-question-and-now-its-gone

Comment: Unfortunately SO doesn't seem to implement any new feature as you described at here , I had similar situation recently, I answer a question and it is not considered as low-quality answer , after receiving my answer, the OP asked many  extra follow-up questions in the same post afterward then quickly deleted the entire post (in 24 hours I believe, I visit SO everyday) . SO should consider new feature in your answer seriously to avoid such askers.

Answer (score 65):

Based on [Brad's idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315406/106435) I would suggest that any question that got an answer can't be deleted by OP for 24, 48 or 72 hours. During this time the community should identify valid and good answers and up vote it.

Once an answer is upvoted, OP can't delete the question anymore.

Comment: Only issue is low traffic tags.  Is 72 hours long enough to be assured of being seen and upvoted?  I'd consider a minimum of views in addition to time to be assured that the answer has been seen by enough people to get upvoted.

Comment: Well, I guess if was are so low traffic it will also be hard for the students to get an answer to copy in the first place.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I think making the timeout too long would lead to people forgetting about coming back to delete it.  There's a tradeoff here with good answers getting deleted because nobody who wanted to upvote saw them yet.  My experience in the x86 asm / sse tags is that even though good answers don't get many upvotes, the votes they do get usually come within hours, not days later.  (For nice answers to not-worth-an-upvote homework questions).  **I think it's better to keep the timeout down to 24h after the last answer is posted**, even though that's not a perfect solution to everything.

Comment: @psubsee2003 then crap questions like the ones caused by typos (the reason it didn't get closed as typo is not getting much views in the first place) can never be voluntarily deleted by OP duo to not getting enough view's ever... see my comment on Brad's answer for an example http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315406/2333214

Answer (score 6):

They will not be able to always [delete question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/299295):

> You can’t delete answers that have been accepted.
>
> You can’t delete your own question when it:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has an accepted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)

It will require some skills, to do that *in-time* (and if student has them, let it be).

Many questions which are too broad get instantly down-voted and closed (doesn't even giving chance to low-reputation guy give a complete answer).

So I'd say *most* of cheaters will fail. And there are other forms of cheating anyway. You have to do it in old-fashion way: exam the guy, test his skills personally. If he was cheating earlier you will easy discover that and then punish him badly.

Another thing, why questions are deleted often? Maybe because someone don't want to show their content and it could be anything: from accidental stupidity attack (e.g. including passwords) and up to a know-how enterprise piece of code. Making it exposed to the public (in-ability to delete question) for a time is a bad move, requiring moderation to be more intensive and then cheaters can exploit it too (editing question, pasting piece of code and say "omg, please, delete it, I shouldn't share my company code").

To summarize: please don't.

Comment: +1 for mentioning cases where showing deleted contents is not desirable, though for serious password exposure's cases, the revision containing it will be wiped anyway.

Comment: I can understand the other close reasons although one should maybe think twice before publishing any potential secrets - after all it can be copied as soon as it's online. However, it should be clear that the homework cheaters deleting their own questions act like parasites - they give absolutely nothing back in return for the help they got here and they will even violate the license by not giving attribution. I would not like to support this practices. Overall it is a difficult issue.

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses the request. It is not asking for people to lose the ability to delete questions. It is asking for the ability to search questions that have been deleted within the past 30 days.

Comment: To clarify, this question is not asking to make them public; questions would still remain deleted (so, not indexed), and would only become searchable by people above 10k or a certain threshold.

Comment: @TylerH, I didn't know when was answering: [I can browse deleted questions of other people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152921/299295) (well, not yet, specifically, but soon in theory), that's a big surprise to me. Well, I suspected moderators can and I am ok with moderators, but not sure if I am ok with hundreds of people.

Comment: @Sinatr At 10,000 reputation you can view deleted posts, as well as use a host of other moderation tools, but you can't *search* for them. You can only view them as you come across the naturally.

Comment: Mistakenly posted sensitive info is *already* handled differently. (For what good it does when search engines crawl SO every few minutes.) There are also surprisingly many questions that don't get closed before a single answer squeaks through; this answer often gets no upvotes, allowing many askers to quietly delete their questions, often abusively. -1.

Answer (score 6):

I think sometimes it is really useful to delete a question immediatly.

I'm thinking about security leaks, for example when someone mistakenly posts some code or a log trace that contains sensitive data (proxy password, ...). Just editing the question isn't enough because the old version still is accessible.

Comment: and it might need some time for the mods to react to the flag asking for revising.

Comment: Google indexes a large chunk of questions scarily fast - basically as soon as you've posted the cat is out of the bag and the **only** thing you can do is invalidate whatever secret was leaked. Deleting outright is the wrong solution and it doesn't even fix it!

Comment: These days two moderators can redact a post and its revision history so that non-moderators cannot see the contents in need of redaction.

Answer (score 4):

Just give the poster an ordinary delete vote like everyone else (5 users needed to make it effective).

Then when they try to delete their question, it'll show up in the [10k delete votes tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today) and find out if anyone else agrees... or disagrees and reverts the edit that replaced the question with "PLZ DELETE cuz I'm not authorized to receive help on this".

Comment: @NathanOliver: Why would it be another?  Don't posts with delete votes already appear in a queue?

Comment: @NathanOliver: You're right it isn't a real "queue", but the [10k delete votes tool](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete) isn't just recently deleted, it's also questions that are partway to deletion.  I'll reword to clarify.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  I just was not sure exactly what you were getting at.

Answer (score -9):

There is something wrong with a project if it is so limited that it can be completed just by asking short questions on Stackoverflow.

**Open ended questions are closed as “too broad”**.  If a student is able to break the task down into lots of small questions they can ask, and then combine the answers so as to create a good project I would not be too concerned about them “cheating”.

As to homework problem, if you wish to check a student has not cheated, you should just interview all students about 1 or 2 of them, not letting the student know beforehand the one you choosen. It will soon become clear if they have cheated.

Expecting Stackoverflow to be change due to you not being willing to put in the effort into effective examine methods, show the same level of afford as a cheating student is making themselves.

Comment: Yes, if you have somehow managed to fit 48 hours into a day, you could do this as a teacher, no problem. However, making such a minimal change would be a way better solution in reality, because in reality teachers don't have time to interview students individually about how they completed each assignment. As for the first part of your question, I find it a little absurd; anyone with that much rep should know it's easy to get hung up on a small part of code, and asking a question here can be just the gentle push you needed to continue on.

Comment: Many introductory programming assignments are not broad. "How can I read a line from a file and then print it on the screen, using `fopen`?"

Comment: You have to defend against 20+ students, and they only have to defeat one teacher per assignment. Students can't be forced to come to you in off-hours for interviews, so you'd have to do that during class time. And what effort are you talking about? You're presuming much about the question that was asked.

Comment: Plagiarism is not only a problem for education. I could be deleting my question so that I don't have to worry about the licensing of the code I'm taking from the answer.

Comment: Come on, learners need simple exercises.  I remember doing a lot of tiny programlets with features like loops and pointers.

Comment: @SList, but they don't need to count towards the passing of the course, there should be a real exam and/or a set of *large* assignments to decide the grade.

Comment: Yes, you have a point there.

Comment: I thought the whole point of software is to make people's lives easier. Are you seriously suggesting that this feature should not be implemented solely because a teacher can manually look into possible cheating attempts (using a method which would take ten times as long)?

Comment: @MageXy, No, I don't believe the feature would allow a teacher to find most cheating attempts.   (There are other sites to student can use etc.)   Also I believe that interviewing students leads to better learning.

Comment: Interviewing students is not realistically feasible. Let's say an interview takes 5 minutes (which I think is the absolute minimum needed to establish that a student has decent knowledge and hasn't cheated). In a class size of 20-30 students, that's an average of about 2 hours, or two class periods. For an individual student, multiple interviews would be most effective for learning, so now the teacher has to set aside even more time. That might even work in a high school setting (though I'm not sure what you'd do with the other students while you're interviewing one), but at a college level...

Comment: ...where there's only so many class sessions, that wastes a ton of time. Regarding my other point, "you can do it manually" should not be a reason to avoid implementing a new feature. There are plenty of other valid possible reasons: "It's not a common use case", "it would take more time to implement than it's worth", "doing this would go against company policy", etc.

Comment: Lots of questions that should be closed are answered before five people can get together to close them.