# I answered a question, and now it's gone

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer

I answered a question about an hour or so ago. The OP commented on it, and I revised my answer as per his comments. The OP seemed content with the answer I provided. As it was a new user I left a comment stating that upvoting or accepting an answer is the usual way to let people know an answer was helpful to you.

Now I can't find my answer or my comments back in my activity, as I don't have enough rep to see deleted posts. I take it that the question itself is removed.

The question was in no way off-topic or of too poor quality to be kept on the site, hence my thought would be that it is self-deleted by the OP. I think this behaviour is somewhat counterproductive to the goal SO as a site has. Is there something that can/should be done about this?

Comment: That has happened to me too. I was under the impression that OP can't delete if there is answers on the question. But it seems they can delete.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the question?

Comment: OP can delete a question with a single unupvoted answer.  Multiple answers or a positive score on the answer will block deletion

Comment: Go to your answers in your profile and you should have a link to **deleted recent answers** at the bottom

Comment: @SurajRao https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171584/vba-transfer-specific-columns-over-to-a-new-sheet/50171742#50171742

Comment: What is multiple? @psubsee2003 as far as I can remember the one that happened to me had two or three answers.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, didn't know that existed.

Comment: yeah OP deleted the question and you had no score. Timeline of the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpGXB.png

Comment: Yeah, waste of my time...

Comment: It sure is frustrating when it happens. As I post most of my posts from phone sometimes as I push post answer I get a message that the answer is deleted. It sucks.

Comment: I voted to undelete the question. Only 2 or 3 more votes to go and the question will be back.

Comment: @Luuklag post it here as a new feature or whatever it's called. That you need answerers permission to delete. I'll upvote it. It is as you say counterproductive for SO.

Comment: @Andreas more than 1 answer will block deletion.  I can't remember if there are any exceptions, but I don't think there are.  Once there are 2 answers, the OP cannot self delete

Comment: @Andreas I don't think getting answerers permission to delete is a good thing per say, but perhaps any question with an answer should be exempt from deletion by OP.

Comment: Odd. I was sure there was more answers. Maybe the other answerers deleted their posts.

Comment: @Luuklag Shog9 is on record saying the question ban algorithm severely pushes a user for doing exactly what was done here, so if they do it enough, the OP will be question banned and will find it difficult to dig out of the hole unless they undelete the question

Comment: Question is undeleted